# How to check fscanf errors in C

Tags: c, file-io, error-handling, scanf

I have a table like this;

```
01 01 02 00 01 02 00 01
01 02 00 01 02 00 01 02
02 00 11 04 04 04 04 04
00 01 10 03 03 03 03 03
```

I am reading this file like this:

```
FILE *map = open_file("lazy.map");
if (map == 0)
    return 0;

for (i = 0; i < TOTAL_TILES; ++i) {
    int ttype;
    fscanf(map,"%i",&ttype);
    // do other stuff here...
}
```

Is there a way that I can check if fscanf failed or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the return value.

Another option is to use `%n` format:

```
int n = -1;
int ttype;
fscanf(map, "%i%n", &ttype, &n);
if(-1 == n)
    // failed to parse
```

This way you can check how many symbols have been consumed by `fscanf`. It doesn't make difference in the above, but in:

```
int count = fscanf(map, "%i abc %n", &ttype, &n);
```

`count` may be greater than one even if `abc` part of the format didn't match. On the other hand, `n` will be set only if the whole format matched.

Answer (score 1):

Yes: you can examine its return-value. Per http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007904975/functions/scanf.html:

> Upon successful completion, these functions shall return the number of successfully matched and assigned input items; this number can be zero in the event of an early matching failure. If the input ends before the first matching failure or conversion, EOF shall be returned. If a read error occurs, the error indicator for the stream is set, EOF shall be returned, and *errno* shall be set to indicate the error.

(That page marks that last part, "and *errno* shall be set to indicate the error", as being POSIX-specific, meaning that the C standard itself doesn't require that *errno* be set; but the rest of it is all required by the C standard.)

Answer (score 0):

Yes. From [C++ reference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/fscanf/):

> Return Value
>
> On success, the function returns the number of items
> successfully read. This count can match the expected number of
> readings or be less -even zero- in the case of a matching failure. In
> the case of an input failure before any data could be successfully
> read, EOF is returned.